# HTML5 appcache - can't get it working offline

Tags: html, html5-appcache

I have a very simple page (I am just learning how to use caching for offline web apps) as below. If I load it on my mobile phone, it works. If I then turn wi-fi off (so there is no internet accessible on my phone now) and reload the page, then it says "Webpage not available". So it is not caching it for some reason. What am I doing wrong?

I am using the Android browser on 4.2.2.

offline.appcache:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# v2.0 : 12-01-2015

CACHE:
index.html

/pouchdb-3.2.1.min.js
/jquery-1.11.2.min.js
```

index.html:

```
<html manifest="/offline.appcache">
    <head>
        <script src="pouchdb-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>


        <h1>Test 2</h1>
        <div id="test"></div>
        <br />
        <button id="test2">CLICK ME</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

.htaccess

```
AddType text/cache-manifest .appcache
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Does it work in other browsers? Do you have android chrome configured to ignore or disable cache? Are you also turning off mobile data?

Comment: I can't remember what I did to fix this actually. It might have been adding a NETWORK part to the appcache file.